# JavaFX center view on cursor position

Tags: java, image, javafx

I created my first JavaFX app that displays images. I want it to zoom the image to full size on mouse down (centered on cursor position) and to refit the image on mouse up.

All is working fine but the i don't know how to center on cursor position. My zoom method looks like that at the moment:

```
private void zoom100(double cursorx, double cursory){
    double centery = imageView.getLayoutBounds().getHeight()/2;
    double centerx = imageView.getLayoutBounds().getWidth()/2;
    imageView.setFitHeight(-1); //zooms height to 100%
    imageView.setFitWidth(-1); //zooms width to 100%
    imageView.setTranslateX(centerx-cursorx); //moves x 
    imageView.setTranslateY(centery-cursory); //moves y
}
```

My idea is to set an offset with translate. I am not sure if translate is the correct approach. If it is the correct approach how to calculate the correct values? (centerx-cursorx) is wrong!

I uploaded the code here: https://github.com/dermoritz/FastImageViewer (it is working now - see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, but i am still not sure if this is a good way to go:

```
private void zoom100(double x, double y) {
    double oldHeight = imageView.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();
    double oldWidth = imageView.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();

    boolean heightLarger = oldHeight>oldWidth;
    imageView.setFitHeight(-1);
    imageView.setFitWidth(-1);
    //calculate scale factor
    double scale=1;
    if(heightLarger){
        scale = imageView.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight()/oldHeight;
    }else {
        scale = imageView.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth()/oldWidth;
    }

    double centery = root.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() / 2;
    double centerx = root.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() / 2;

    double xOffset = scale * (centerx - x);
    double yOffset = scale *(centery - y);
    imageView.setTranslateX(xOffset);
    imageView.setTranslateY(yOffset);

}
```

The picture must be centered within "root". I think there should be something more direct - only using properties of imageview?!

Meanwhile the app works using this code: https://github.com/dermoritz/FastImageViewer

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but I think the order is wrong. you calculate the center before you set the fit size. By setting the fit size your image view will change it's preferred size. therefore the center point won't match anymore.

Comment: no it is not working, i think using translate is the problem, but iam not sure

Comment: In what Layout Pane is the image view placed? Can you give a small running example?

Comment: i added a link to github, i used the example from oracle, the ImageView is placed in a stack pane. Meanwhile i changed the code - translate comes first to center the image, then zoom. but the centering isn't working.